# Is there any way to iterate the decimal part of a double var in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, iteration, double, decimal

What i'm looking for:

Given a Double (doublenumber) and an Int (n) I wish to iterate trough the 1st decimal, 2nd decimal, 3rd decimal, 4th decimal.... until the 'n'decimal

My first approach was, coverting to String the Double so I could iterate like an array the string, but the problem is that when I convert to string I lose many decimals numbers

```
    let doubleNumber = 1.00/98                  //0.010204081632653061224489795918367346938775510204081632653...
    var stringFromDouble = String(doubleNumber) //0.010204081632653
    stringFromDouble.removeFirst()              //.010204081632653
    stringFromDouble.removeFirst()              //010204081632653

    for letter in stringFromDouble{
      //cycle to iterate the decimals
    }
```

Comment: What is max limit of decimal numbers to which you want to iterate?

Comment: @PGDev it could be from 1 to 'n'  with the condition ('n' >= 1)

Comment: Your first problem is that the precision of Double is limited, it is roughly  16 decimal digits. Therefore `1.0/98.0` is not computed as 0.010204081632653061224489795918367346938775510204081632653.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the intention is to get *many* decimal digits of `1.0/98.0` then you must not store that number in a `Double` in the first place, because that has a precision of approximately 16 decimal digits only. You could use `Decimal` which has a precision of 38 decimal digits.

But for more decimal digits you'll have to do “rational arithmetic,” i.e. work with numerator and denominator of the fraction as *integers.*

Here is how you can print arbitrarily many decimal digits of a rational number. For simplicity I have assumed that the number is positive and less than one.

```
func printDecimalDigits(of numerator: Int, dividedBy denominator: Int, count: Int) {
    var numerator = numerator
    for _ in 1...count {
        // Multiply by 10 to get the next digit:
        numerator *= 10
        // Print integer part of `numerator/denominator`:
        print(numerator / denominator, terminator: "")
        // Reduce `numerator/denominator` to its fractional part:
        numerator %= denominator
    }
    print()
}
```

Example:

```
printDecimalDigits(of: 1, dividedBy: 98, count: 100)
// 0102040816326530612244897959183673469387755102040816326530612244897959183673469387755102040816326530
```

Or as a function which returns the digits as a (lazily evaluated) *sequence:*

```
func decimalDigits(of numerator: Int, dividedBy denominator: Int) -> AnySequence<Int> {
    return AnySequence(sequence(state: numerator) { num -> Int in
        num *= 10
        let d = num / denominator
        num %= denominator
        return d
    })
}
```

Example:

```
let first1000Digits = decimalDigits(of: 1, dividedBy: 98).prefix(1000)
for d in first1000Digits { print(d) }
```